# When submitting multiple values, execute() method doesn't run

Tags: javascript, struts2, request, action, http-request-parameters

I need to submit some values as request params (through javascript) which I need to use in my `Action` class. I was able to post some data before this way and retrieve in the `Action` class. But now it doesn't seem to work.

When I just submit the `code=001`,

```
document.forms[0].action='test.action?code='+code;
```

I am able to retrieve this value in the `execute()` method of `Action` class using `request.getParameter("code");`

However, when I try to submit two values:

```
var code='001';

var values='Title:The Boy, Type:Mandatory';

document.forms[0].action='test.action?code='+code+'&values='+values;
```

In this case, the call does not even come into the execute method (I have a sysout in the execute method).

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here? I don't understand.....

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Try `...'&values='+escape(values);` - you should  escape the special characters before passing them into the URL. This should work IMO. `escape()` is a javascript function specifically meant for this

Comment: show us the URL as these parameters must be coming in URL.also you no need to use `request.getParameter()`

Comment: When only the code is sent,the url is --- http://localhost:8080/Com/test.action?code=1001....And when i need to send more params like values, then the url is ------ http://localhost:8080/Com/test.action?code=1001&values=FUEL:PETROL, POWER:KW, Wheel Configuration:4X2, CABIN:SINGLE CAB, TRANSMISSION:FULLY AUTOMATIC, Steering: LHD

Comment: Hi, as advised by Nupul, I used document.forms[0].action='test.action?code='+code+'&values='+escape(values); in javascript but still the execute() method was not called.

Comment: In my action class, I have used ------
public String execute(){
   ctx = ActionContext.getContext();
   request = ((HttpServletRequest)this.ctx.get("com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest"));
   session = this.request.getSession();
  
  System.out.println("INSIDE EXECUTE************************");
  
  System.out.println("___________INSIDE ACTION______from REquest_________-"+request.getAttribute("code"));
  System.out.println("___________INSIDE ACTION______from REquest_________-"+request.getAttribute("values"));

Comment: @ITAmateur When adding information about the original question, please edit the original question--code posted in comments is illegible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with using javascript.But here is what we can do to let struts2 work for you

in your action class create 2 properties

```
   private String code
   private String values
// create there getter and setter outside of execute method
```

now when you submit your values for e.g in your case

```
 localhost:8080/Com/test.action?code=1001&values=FUEL:PETROL, POWER:KW, Wheel 
Configuration:4X2, CABIN:SINGLE CAB, TRANSMISSION:FULLY AUTOMATIC, Steering: LHD
```

struts2 build in interceptor stack will try to find property with the name code,values in your action class and since you have already specified setter methods for these properties ,struts2 will try to set the values in these properties.

while trying to set the properties it will look in to the data type you have specified for your properties, build in system will look for out of the box type convertors it has and will try to convert the data type as per your requirements.
if it has that type convertor it will do work for you else will throw an exception that it is unable to convert the given value to the specified value.

FYI:

Struts2 provides a clean way to separate your code from underlying `Servlet API` so there is no need to use `request.getParameter()` or `ActionContext.getContext()` as framework will doing all this work for you and providing you everything inside your action class in clean way

here is the code working for me

**JSP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){

    var code='001';

    var values='values=FUEL:PETROL, POWER:KW, Wheel Configuration:4X2, CABIN:SINGLE CAB, TRANSMISSION:FULLY AUTOMATIC, Steering: LHD';
     var value='demo.action?code='+code+'&values='+values;;
     alert(value);
    document.demo.action=value;
    document.demo.submit();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="demo" name="demo" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="test()">

</form>
```

and here is Action class

```
private String code;
private String values;

public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(String values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
 public String execute(){
      System.out.println("**************************"+code);
      System.out.println(values);
 }
```

here is the console output

```
**************************001
FUEL:PETROL, POWER:KW, Wheel Configuration:4X2, CABIN:SINGLE CAB, 
TRANSMISSION:FULLY AUTOMATIC, Steering: LHD
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this.I have a bean with the same variables. But my problem is once i try to include both code and values in my url, the code does not enter the execute() method. If only code is sent in the url, it is coming to execute() method.Can you help me here.

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't understand your question well, but I guess you are looking for this

```
<s:url id="urlid" action="anyaction" escapeAmp="false">
       <s:param name="param1">value1</s:param>
       <s:param name="param2">value2</s:param>
 </s:url>
```

If you don't set escapeAmp="false" then you can send only 1 variable.